# Are $\cos$ and $\sin$ linearly dependent in $[- π , π]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Are $\cos$ and $\sin$ linearly dependent on $[- π , π]$ If true, demonstrate; if False show a counterexample.

Comment: If they were dependent, you would have something like $\sin / \cos =$ a scalar. What do you think about it?

Comment: Hint:

The general idea in order to prove the linear independence is showing that if there exists constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ s.t. $$c_1\cos x + c_2\sin x = 0$$ for all $x$ in $[-\pi, \pi]$ then $c_1=c_2=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Check the Wronskian of the two functions.

Comment: So they are always linearly independent ?

Comment: @user243934 What you do mean, "always?"

Answer (score 3):

Assume as a contraddiction that there exists $(a,b)\neq(0,0)$ such that $\forall x\in[-\pi,\pi]\ a\sin x+b\cos x=0$

Then, for all $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ it would hold
$$\begin{cases}\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1\\a\sin x+b\cos x=0\end{cases}$$

But the system 
$$\begin{cases}t^2+s^2=1\\at +bs=0\end{cases}$$
has exactly $2$ solutions, which would imply that $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are bound to assume at most $2$ values each on a real interval...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: find two values $x_1, x_2$ for which the values of $\sin x_i$ are different, but the values of $\cos x_i$ are the same.